# Access content in JQuery when clicking on other div's image

Tags: jquery, html, select

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="field1"></div>
    <div class="field2">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="field3">
        <div class="content">Lorum Ipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to access the content of my `.field3` div when clicking on the `.field2 img`. And I would like to do so with the minimum of code...

```
$('.wrapper1 img').click(function(){
    var desc = $(this).find('.field3').html();
    console.log(desc);
});
```

But for some reason, I get an empty object. Ofcourse, this makes sense (because it's looking for a `field3` inside the `this`-element (which in this case is the image), but how can I tackle this issue in JQ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery select parent elements sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043969/jquery-select-parent-elements-sibling)

Comment: You can find a list of all DOM traversal methods here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/. Once you know in which direction you want to go, you just have to find the right method for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.wrapper1 img').click(function(){
    var desc = $(this).parent().siblings('.field3').html();
    console.log(desc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` will look for descendants of the element clicked, but field3 isn't a descendant. You can access it directly:

```
$('.wrapper1 img').click(function(){
    var desc = $('.field3').html();
    console.log(desc);
});
```

Or navigate to the parent and then use find:

```
$('.wrapper1 img').click(function(){
    var desc = $(this).closest('.wrapper1').find('.field3').html();
    console.log(desc);
});
```

Note that the second way will be slower since you will be navigating a hierarchy, but it will be helpful if you have several elements with the `field3` class and want to pick the one that is in the same `wrapper1` element as the `img` that was clicked.

Comment: +1 for the first part, which is the easiest and the most simple way to go.

Comment: It's better to use `.closest` instead of `.parents` here.

Comment: @Michiel `closest` returns the first ancestor that matches the selector, while `parents` will find all ancestors. If you find all ancestors, then you lose the advantage the second approach has, which is finding a specific `field3` element.

Comment: @Michiel: In addition to what cfs said, `.closest` will *stop* searching when it found a match, while `.parents` will always traverse to the top of the document.

Comment: Actualy, it would be better to use `parent()` which returns the first parent of the actual element. it **IS** different from `parents()`.

Comment: @Ghillied If by better you mean faster, you're probably right. This will depend on how many siblings there are though, since you'll have to filter the sibling elements (as in your answer). On balance, they probably aren't very different...

Comment: @cfs That's true, siblings is another factor for effiency and performance. Going top down (`$('.field3')`) could be better. 
http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-selector/8

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.wrapper1 img').click(function(){
    var desc = $(this).parents(".wrapper1").children('.field3').html();
    console.log(desc);
});
```